# GMT Offset with inputs: latitude and longitude

Tags: java

If I pass latitude and longitude, In response I need GMT time zone value.

For Example:

- latitude: 21.7679
- longitude: 78.8718
- Response excepted: GMT+05:30

I don't want to use any webservice.

Comment: Without using an online resource of some sort, or a database of time-zone polygon definitions, you will struggle to implement this yourself as there is not a simple function from longitude to time zone.  Look at a map of world time zones if you doubt this; even at longitude 0 there are multiple time zones.  Oh, and GMT is so last century, UTC is when it's at now man.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark *GMT is so last century,*. Gave me a laugh.

Answer (score 2):

You will need quite a lot of information in order to get precise results if you do not want to use a web service. There is a hack however, which will easily give approximate results:

```
Divide longitude by 15
```

According to [www.timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html):

...
Each time zone is then theoretically 15 degrees wide, corresponding to a one-hour difference in mean solar time. The shape of time zones is changed, in practice, to match internal and international borders. Civil time changes by one hour forward and backward respectively for every 15 degrees east or west of the Greenwich Meridian. One would need to divide the longitude, in degrees, by 15 to find the appropriate time zone, in hours. For example:

```
At 150 degrees west (or 150° W) longitude, the time should be 150 degrees divided by 15 degrees = 10 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC/GMT) (or UTC-10).
At 75 degrees east (or 75° E) longitude, the time would be 75 degrees divided by 15 degrees = 5 hours ahead of UTC/GMT (or UTC+5).
```

Comment: To be pedantic the time zones don't change every +/-15deg from the prime meridian, time zone 0 is centred on the prime meridian, the next zones east and west start at +/-7.5deg.  And, to illustrate my comment on the question, this method fails for OP's example; it will not produce an offset of 5h30m for longitudes in India.

Comment: Fair enough! This is why is wrote _approximate results_... I would use a web service.