# Calculate GMT Offset from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, time, latitude-longitude, offset

I need to calculate GMT Offset from latitude and longitude. I have tried to do it as below.

```
offset = direction * longitude * 24 / 360
```

I need to know, is this correct for Daylight Savings Time offsets ? if not, how can i calculate GMT Offset from latitude and longitude for Daylight Savings Time offsets ?

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to do with longitude, you need to know the country & region you're in.

Timezones are not split by longitude exactly and not all countries use daylight savings.

For example, China uses a single timezone but is wide enough to cover 5 other timezones. [See map.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Timezones2008.png)

Comment: Yes. Not all countries use daylight savings. `offset = direction * longitude * 24 / 360` is correct for those countries. but i need to know is this correct for daylight savings countries ?

Answer (score 0):

this is correct

```
offset = direction * longitude * 24 / 360
```

where direction is 1 for east, -1 for west, and longitude is in (-180,180)

beside this

```
Divide longitude by 15
```

According to [www.timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html):

> Each time zone is then theoretically 15 degrees wide, corresponding
>   to a one-hour difference in mean solar time. The shape of time zones
>   is changed, in practice, to match internal and international borders.
>   Civil time changes by one hour forward and backward respectively for
>   every 15 degrees east or west of the Greenwich Meridian. One would
>   need to divide the longitude, in degrees, by 15 to find the
>   appropriate time zone, in hours. For example:
>
> ```
> At 150 degrees west (or 150° W) longitude, the time should be 150 degrees divided by 15 degrees = 10 hours behind Coordinated Universal
> ```
>
> Time (UTC/GMT) (or UTC-10).
>       At 75 degrees east (or 75° E) longitude, the time would be 75 degrees divided by 15 degrees = 5 hours ahead of UTC/GMT (or UTC+5).

Comment: I konw `offset = direction * longitude * 24 / 360` is correct if there is no Daylight Savings. but i need to know is this correct for when we are on Daylight Savings ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that last section is drawn from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988456/gmt-offset-with-inputs-latitude-and-longitude/17988666#17988666 , but in any case you need to properly blockquote this.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplistic formula can't possibly be correct, as it makes no distinction between northern and southern hemispheres (i.e. latitude). In northern latitudes DST starts about March, in southern latitudes it starts in September or October. In any case not all countries use DST as has been pointed out in a previous answer.